# How to pipe python subprocess to batch command in linux? (subprocess runs bash command that calls a python script)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, subprocess

I am trying to use run a python script by piping it to the `batch` command of linux to basically form a task queue. This requires that my python subprocess be spawned by bash instead of just spawning the python script directly in the subprocess, so the subprocess is sort of nested, I guess. The python script runs and succeeds, in that it outputs a text file and the process gives me a `returncode` of `0`, but it doesn't clear from the queue if I check `atq` in the terminal and the `stderr` of the process prints the job number indicating there is some sort of error. I don't know how to get a more detailed error message from the shell so if anyone has information on that, I'm all ears. I think the `batch` command is supposed to send an email if there's an error, but I've never gotten one.

How I am calling the subprocess:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sh", "-c", f"python ./atqTest/hello.py --stuff 1980 | batch"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = process.communicate()
print(f'out: {out.decode()}')
print(f'err: {err.decode()}')
print(process.returncode)
```

What `hello.py` looks like:

```
import sys, argparse

def parse_args(args):
    """Parses command line agruments."""

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="""do stuff""",
        usage="""--stuff <random arg>\n"""
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "--stuff",
        required=True,
        help="""put something in"""
    )

    return parser.parse_args(args)

def main():
    parser = parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

    with open(f'/Documents/test/test.txt', 'w') as f:
        for item in parser.stuff:
            f.write(item + '\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output I get:

```
out: 
err: job 94 at Thu Aug 17 10:01:23 2023
0
```

After typing `atq` in the terminal to check the subprocess status (you can see it's not running):

```
94      Thu Aug 17 10:01:00 2023
```

I have also tried using this to call the process but it doesn't make a difference:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(f"python ./atqTest/hello.py --stuff 1980 | batch", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to use run a python script by piping it to the batch command of linux to basically form a task queue.

The `batch` command expects to read the text of one or more shell commands from its standard input.  It executes those commands at a time of its choosing.  You are instead running a command immediately, and feeding its (empty in this case) *output* to `batch`.

> This requires that my python subprocess be spawned by bash

No, it requires the Python script to be spawned by *`batch`*.

> instead of just spawning the python script directly in the subprocess,

Yes, the whole point of using `batch` is that `batch` chooses when to run the script, instead of it being run directly.

Although you can use a shell pipe to feed input to `batch`, I don't see any reason to use one here, nor to involve `bash` at all.  Just run `batch`, and `communicate()` the wanted command to it:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["batch"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = process.communicate(b'python ./atqTest/hello.py --stuff 1980')
print(f'out: {out.decode()}')
print(f'err: {err.decode()}')
print(process.returncode)
```

Alternatively, moving a little further from your original code, you could use `subprocess.run()` instead of `subprocess.Popen()`:

```
result = subprocess.run(["batch"], input=b'python ./atqTest/hello.py --stuff 1980',
        capture_output=True)

print(f'out: {result.stdout.decode()}')
print(f'err: {result.stderr.decode()}')
print(result.returncode)
```

Comment: Though probably also prefer `subprocess.run` over `Popen`, as also suggested in the `subprocess` documentation. It will basically simplify this to a one-liner, and add useful error checking etc.

Comment: @John Bollinger - I had to add `text=True` to the `Popen` to get this to work as it was looking for a byte obj otherwise. Thanks. I converted it to use `subprocess.run` as well. I ended up with this `process = subprocess.run(['batch'], input='python ./atqTest/hello.py --stuff 1980', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)`

The job now clears the queue, however I still get output from `print(f'err: {process.stderr}')` that looks the same as in my original post. Strange.

Comment: Yes, @MKF, my bad (now corrected): if you do not specify text mode then you need to provide bytes for the subprocess's input and you get back bytes from its output and error streams.  If you do specify text mode then input, output, and error are all strings instead.  In general, which one you want may vary.

Comment: As for the stderr, @MKF, yes: `batch` emits a status message to its stderr stream.  You should not interpret this as an *error message*, however.  Despite the name, stderr is used for many more purposes than just that.  Use the `returncode` to check whether it succeeded: by convention, 0 means success and nonzero means failure.